# SQL LIMIT keyword: Ensure a specific result is included

Tags: sql, limit

I need to write an SQL prefetcher along the lines of

```
SELECT * WHERE id == x OR id >= y LIMIT 100 FROM ...
```

where I need the result id == x to be included, while the other results are just bonus. Is this possible? If not, I am thinking if the ids are sorted, and the returned results are in their ordering, I can still make the query in a way where it is guaranteed to include id == x. But could be tricky.

Edit: So the answer(from rbm) is this:

```
(SELECT * WHERE id == x)
UNION
(SELECT * WHERE id > y LIMIT 100)
```

Note: It's ok that I may have +-1 number of results

Comment: You need two selects and union. Your `id == x OR id >= y` wouldn't guarantee that `id==x` would get selected.

Comment: It is possible but you have the SQL constructed all wonky. It goes ```SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ... LIMIT ...```. Also, tag your database please.

Comment: @Anand, no, that won't guarantee that `id==x` is included.

Comment: @rbm `SELECT * WHERE ... LIMIT ... FROM ...` isn't a SQL syntax at best.

Comment: @rbm, I'm not sure what you are talking about. A row with ```id = x``` will appear in the select results if it exists in the table using the ```OR``` condition. It will not appear in the results if it doesn't exist in the table even if you use a ```UNION```. There is no such thing as guarantee :)

Comment: @rbm this will do the trick?

    (SELECT * WHERE id == x)
    UNION
    (SELECT * WHERE id > y LIMIT 100)

Comment: @user2154768 yes

Comment: @Anand not if the condition is `id == x OR id >= y`. Imagine there are ids from 1 to 10000 and you say `id == 1000 OR id >= 3000` - you're not guaranteed that the first 100 (of whatever the limit is) has the 100, unless you sort them somehow. But using the `union` you are guaranteed that if such `id` exists, it will be included

Comment: @rbm, I know that and even in that case, a UNION is not strictly needed. See my comment on the first answer below; that will also guarantee without using union. However, my first comment was about it being possible and how the SQL itself was constructed wonky and I stand by that comment :)

Answer (score 2):

If you need id = x to be included, do something like this:

```
select case when id = x then 1 else 2 end sortOrder
etc
order by sortOrder
```

Comment: I see the point about the limit cutting off rows so you can use this to make sure that it isn't cutoff.

Answer (score 1):

After putting it to SQL syntax, it would look like :

```
SELECT *
FROM ...
WHERE id = x OR id >= y
ORDER BY CASE WHEN id = x THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC
LIMIT 100
```

EDIT : Reminder: Limit is applied after order.